# How to convert a componentDidUpdate to useEffect when prevProps are used in a nested if/else statement?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm not sure how to convert this section to fit into a useEffect. I can't pull the prevProps conditional out since it should only run within the loop. I dont think I can just add the props to dependency array either, as I need to do something else whenever selectedCurrency does **not** change.

```
public componentDidUpdate(prevProps: Readonly<Props>): void {
if (api != null) {
const MyData: {}[] = [];
            api.forEach(el=> {
                if (!el.data) {
                    return;
                }
                if (selectedCurrency === "") {
                    el.setDataValue("val1", "-");
                    el.setDataValue("val2", "-");
                    el.setDataValue("val3", "-");
                    el.setDataValue("val4", "-");
                } else {
                    const originalCcy = el.data.Currency;
                    const exchangeRate = referenceCurrencies
                        .filter(x => x.originalCurrency === originalCcy)
                        .flatMap(value => value.conversionCurrencies)
                        .find(value => value.currency === selectedCurrency);
                    const middleMarketRate = exchangeRate ? exchangeRate.middleMarketRate : 1;

                    el.setDataValue("val2", el.data.val2 * middleMarketRate);
                    el.setDataValue(
                        "val3",
                        el.data.val3 * middleMarketRate
                    );
                    el.setDataValue("val1", middleMarketRate);
                    if (
                        prevProps.dateFrom === dateFrom &&
                        prevProps.dateTo === dateTo &&
                        prevProps.selectedCurrency !== selectedCurrency
                    ) {
                        const dateToMoment = moment(dateTo);
                        const dateFromMoment = moment(dateFrom);

                        const totalValBalCols = dateToMoment.diff(dateFromMoment, "days");

                        for (let i = 0; i <= totalValBalCols; i += 1) {
                            const dayDiff = i;
                            const currentDate = moment(dateFrom)
                                .add(dayDiff, "days")
                                .format("DD-MMM-YYYY");
                            el.setDataValue(
                                "refCol",
                                el.data[currentDate]
                            );
                        }
                    } else {
                        MyData.push(el.data);
                    }
                }
          });
     }
}
```

Comment: can you say what this code is doing. i.e in your own words. can you give some context to what the if else is doing. they might be a better design approach.

Comment: Added some code for context. Essentially it updates some grid data when the selectedCurrency updates

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useRef()` to hold the previous props, with a 2nd `useEffect()` to update `preProps.current` after you check if anything changed.

Example (not tested):

```
const prevProps = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
  // skip the effect since this is the initial render
  if(!prevProps.current) return;

  api?.forEach(el => {
    if (!el.data) return;
    
    if (selectedCurrency === "") {
      // Do something    
      return;
    }
    
    if (
        prevProps.current.dateFrom === dateFrom &&
        prevProps.current.dateTo === dateTo &&
        prevProps.current.selectedCurrency !== selectedCurrency
    ) {
      //Do something
      return;
    }
    
    //Do something else
  });

}, [api, dateFrom, dateTo, selectedCurrency]);

useEffect(() => { prevProps.current = props; })
```